# How to add a dropdown list in an outlook meeting request by means of a custom add-in?

Tags: javascript, html, office365, dropdown, outlook-addin

I want to create an outlook web add-in, (not COM or VSTO) which upon activation, will include a dropdown list with a predefined list of values.

However this dropdown list should appear in the red region, please see screenshot, and not in a task pane.

[dropdown screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I8uX.png)

The add-in will be for Office365

The [outlook add-in tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial) only shows how to work with a task pane. Any idea on how I can proceed with this? any links or piece of codes are welcome.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook Web add-ins don't provide anything for customizing the specified area.

In case of COM add-ins, you may consider using Windows API for subclassing Outlook windows and injecting your own UI anywhere. See [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a) sample project.